# ExtJS 4.2.2 ComboBox fields show up behind Window

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, extjs4.2

I'm having an issue where I pop up a window with a loaded comboBox, and when I click on it, the fields show up *behind* the window.

Thinking I may be using some setting wrong, I created a small test based off the documentation of the ComboBox, and it does it here for me as well. *(If you try it, may need to drag the bottom of the window up to see the options)*

```
showTestWindow = function() {
var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
    data : [
        {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
        {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
        {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
        //...
    ]
});

var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 525,
    height: 280,
    items: [// Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
                {
        xtype: 'combobox',
            fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
            store: states,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'abbr'
                }
    ]
}).show();
}
```

I created a JSFiddle, but it doesn't have the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/N9VUr/ (I assume something is different about the JSFiddle environment?)

I've tried this with both Firefox and Internet Explorer

Is this a Sencha bug, or am I doing something wrong? What's the easiest way to fix this?

**Edit**

Also, reassurance that it isn't just my local settings or something on my end would be appreciated if I could get someone else to test it as well.

Screenshot:
[image: example screenshot]

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your issue here. Are you able to post a screenshot of it? Also, try setting property [modal](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-modal) on the window.

Comment: posted screenshot; I have tried modal but no effect, other than blurring the combolist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest solution if you rush for a fix is by adding css.

```
.x-combo-list{z-index:100000 !important;}
```

Comment: This was the best way to solve it. After doing some looking I also saw that for whatever reason we were changing the z-index of the window in our css, causing it to be higher than usual.

Comment: It really is better not to change the z-index. ExtJs is setting the z-index correctly. So once you start to modifiy it for one element, you will be forced to change it for another, then another, and later againg another...

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you observe could be related to the fact that you create the combo before the window.

Use xtype to defer the creation of the checkbox to the rendering of the window.

```
var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    width: 525,
    height: 280,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr'
    }]
}).show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but no effect from using the xtype. Changed my code to reflect this however, since that is how most people will want to view it I think.

Comment: I have no idea where to look. As you say the fiddle is working... So there must be a difference in your case. Good luck to find it !

Comment: You were right, I had to start looking through the css to find my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be caused by error in other block of code on current page. This opinion based on my own experience

Comment: Happened to me before too, unfortunately this happens with only the above code. Other than the `Ext.onReady()` calling that function.