# ExtJs 6, Combo box is datefield are covered by other component

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I try create a sample using Extjs 6.5.2

but combo box items list and date calendar picker is covered by other component.
the following picture is a datefield component

[image]
```

```
    var containerPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        renderTo: 'wrapperId',
        layout: 'column',
        suspendLayouts: true,
        defaults: {
            padding: 3,
            labelStyle: 'white-space: nowrap; width: 170px;',
        },
    });

    containerPanel.add({
        xtype: 'datefield',
        fieldLabel: 'Date of Birth',
        name: 'birthDate',
        columnWidth: 1
    });

    containerPanel.add({
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Age',
        name: 'age',
        columnWidth: 1
    });

    containerPanel.add({
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        fieldLabel: 'is Single',
        columnWidth: 1,
        layout: 'hbox',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                boxLabel: '',
                name: 'isSingle',
                inputValue: '1',
            }
        ]
    });

   var panelA = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        layout: 'column',
        suspendLayouts: true,
        defaults: {
            padding: 3,
            labelStyle: 'white-space: nowrap; width: 100px;',
        },
    });

    containerPanel.add({
        xtype: 'tabpanel',
        columnWidth: 1,
        fullscreen: true,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Panel A',
                items: [panelA]
            },
            {
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                title: 'Panel B',
                html: 'Content B'
            },
            {
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                title: 'Panel C',
                html: 'Content C'
            },
            {
                styleHtmlContent: true,
                title: 'Panel D',
                html: 'Content D'
            }
        ]
    });
```

```

I found a post like my issue.
but the solution seem not work for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21129817/5180366

And combo box items list also cannot be shown if a component is place on its next row.
Thanks.

Comment: which browser you are using and version ?

Comment: Please test this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2alf)** in your browser and you are getting same issue ?

Comment: Not found. Please mentioned browser info. link: http://www.jsonwrapper.com/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=tags&utm_campaign=queries

Comment: @Njdhv, sorry for my missing mention,  I do it on IE11.

Comment: I think its css issue. please check z-index value of datefield

Comment: @Njdhv , no problem for this [FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2alf), but i don't know why the code fail on my environment (this is on gwt client side :( )